# My simple python unittest case not running as expected

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

Created this simple unit test as shown bellow

**calculator_tester.py**

```
import unittest
class MathsTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_createOperation(self):
        operation = Mathoperation()
```

This is the only test file I have created and **Note** ***there doesnot exist a class call Mathoperation()*** that is defined inside the test method.
n
When running this sample test code using the python test runner

```
python -m unittest
```

output:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

**Expectation:**

> I was expecting the test case to run and throw NameError: global name
>   Mathoperation is not defined. But the test case didn't run.

What is the sample test case not running. I am running it on **python version 2.7.12**

Answer (score 1):

[Test discovery](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest-test-discovery) looks for files matching the glob pattern `test*.py` by default. Your test doesn't match that pattern. Rename it, or specify the test file explicitly.